# sending receiving images Parse server (Android) and populate in listview keeping order

Tags: android, parse-server

In chat application, I am using Parse server. I want to send text and images.
Images are not receiving in the same order as it was send to the server due to call back method. I am displaying images in listView when images are retrieved fully via callBAck method. So that, order of images are disturbed.

In different chat Applications, the imageView is displayed first & then image is displayed after retrieval from server. I want to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must to make sure that you are reusing the table view cells either via recyclerview or with view holders. Then i recommend you to use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) which will really reduce all the complexity in dealing with images and caching of images.

This is what i did in one of the adapters in one of my projects:

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            CoverImage coverImage = coverImages.get(position);

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_cover_image, parent, false);
                holder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coverImageNameTextView);
                holder.coverImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coverImageView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.nameTextView.setText(coverImage.getName());

            com.tasksforce.honeydo.parse.model.CoverImage customCoverImage = User.currentUser().getCoverPhotoWithKey(coverImage.getKey());

            if (customCoverImage != null && customCoverImage.getImage() != null) {
                Picasso.with(getContext())
                        .load(customCoverImage.getImage()
                                .getUrl())
                        .into(holder.coverImageView);
            } else {
                try {
                    holder.coverImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageUtils.getBitmapFromAssets(getContext(), coverImage.getKey()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            return convertView;
        }
```

As you can see from the code, I reuse the cells then i use Picasso to load the image (i also use parse-server so your code should look similar)